# Applying Algorithm to multiple files

Tags: c#, algorithm, file, sorting

I'm currently working on a project where I have to choose a file and then sort it along with other files. The files are just filled with numbers but each file has linked data. So the first number in a file is linked to the first number in the second file and so on. I Currently have code that allows me to read a file and display the file unsorted and sorted using the bubble sort. I am not sure how I would be able to apply this same principle to multiple files at once. So that I could choose a file and then sort it in line with the same method I have for a single file.

Currently, the program loads and asks the user to choose between 1 and 2. 1 Shows the code unsorted and 2 shows the code sorted. I can read in the files but the problem is sorting and displaying in order. Basically How do I sort multiple files that are linked together. What steps do I need to take to do this?

An example of one file:

```
4    
28    
77    
96
```

An example of the second file:

```
66.698    
74.58    
2.54    
48.657
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public class Program

{
public Program()
{ 
}

public void ReadFile(int [] numbers)
{
    string path = "Data1/Day_1.txt";
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);


    for (int index = 0; index < numbers.Length; index++)
    {
        numbers[index] = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine());
    }

    sr.Close(); // closes file when done
}

public void SortArray(int[] numbers)
{
    bool swap;
    int temp;

    do
    {
        swap = false;
        for (int index = 0; index < (numbers.Length - 1); index++)
        {
            if (numbers[index] > numbers[index + 1])
            {
                temp = numbers[index];
                numbers[index] = numbers[index + 1];
                numbers[index + 1] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swap == true);
 }

public void DisplayArray(int[] numbers)
{
    for(int index = 0; index < numbers.Length; index++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", numbers[index]);
    }
  }
}
```

The main is in another file to keep work organised:

using System;

```
public class FileDemoTest
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] numbers = new int[300];
    Program obj = new Program();
    int operation = 0;


    Console.WriteLine("1 or 2 ?");
    operation = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    // call the read from file method
    obj.ReadFile(numbers);

    if (operation == 1)
    {
        //Display unsorted values
        Console.Write("Unsorted:");
        obj.DisplayArray(numbers);
    }

    if (operation == 2)
    {
        //sort numbers and display
        obj.SortArray(numbers);
        Console.Write("Sorted: ");
        obj.DisplayArray(numbers);
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not stated clearly enough to be answered.  Please work on clarifying the problem statement.

Comment: Updated briefly. Much of what I need help with is stated in there

Comment: You provided an example of the input that will be coming in (file 1 and file 2), but you have not provided an example of the output you expect. To me it sounds like you want to sort file 1 but retain each line's relationship with it's counterpart in file 2, but it's really not clear if that's what you want, or if you want to sort both files independently from each other.

Comment: Also, do you want to save the files in their sorted state, or are you just sorting it in memory for display to the user?

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what im trying to do. Retain the relationship between file 1 and 2 but sort the column of file one out. If you understand me? For now just want to output them. I can add that function later on to save them

Comment: Are all the values in File 1 unique, or are there repetitions?

Comment: There are some repetitions

Comment: So basically you want to reorder the lines of the second file in the same way the lines in the first file were reordered? Just load them into tuples and sort the tuples according to the data and write back to the files afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is create a class that will hold the values from file 1 and file 2. Then you can populate a list of these classes by reading values from both files. After that, you can sort the list of classes on either field, and the relationships will be maintained (since the two values are stored in a single object).

Here's an example of the class that would hold the file data:

```
public class FileData
{
    public int File1Value { get; set; }
    public decimal File2Value { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a friendly string representation of this object
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A string showing the File1 and File2 values</returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{File1Value}: {File2Value}";
    }
}
```

Then you can create a method that reads both files and creates and returns a list of these objects:

```
public static FileData[] GetFileData(string firstFilePath, string secondFilePath)
{
    // These guys hold the strongly typed version of the string values in the files
    int intHolder = 0;
    decimal decHolder = 0;

    // Get a list of ints from the first file
    var fileOneValues = File
        .ReadAllLines(firstFilePath)
        .Where(line => int.TryParse(line, out intHolder))
        .Select(v => intHolder)
        .ToArray();

    // Get a list of decimals from the second file
    var fileTwoValues = File
        .ReadAllLines(secondFilePath)
        .Where(line => decimal.TryParse(line, out decHolder))
        .Select(v => decHolder)
        .ToArray();

    // I guess the file lengths should match, but in case they don't, 
    // use the size of the smaller one so we have matches for all items
    var numItems = Math.Min(fileOneValues.Count(), fileTwoValues.Count());

    // Populate an array of new FileData objects
    var fileData = new FileData[numItems];
    for (var index = 0; index < numItems; index++)
    {
        fileData[index] = new FileData
        {
            File1Value = fileOneValues[index],
            File2Value = fileTwoValues[index]
        };
    }

    return fileData;
}
```

Now, we need to modify your sorting method to work on a FileData array instead of an int array. I also added an argument that, if set to false, will sort on the File2Data field instead of File1Data:

```
public static void SortArray(FileData[] fileData, bool sortOnFile1Data = true)
{
    bool swap;

    do
    {
        swap = false;
        for (int index = 0; index < (fileData.Length - 1); index++)
        {
            bool comparison = sortOnFile1Data
                ? fileData[index].File1Value > fileData[index + 1].File1Value
                : fileData[index].File2Value > fileData[index + 1].File2Value;

            if (comparison)
            {
                var temp = fileData[index];
                fileData[index] = fileData[index + 1];
                fileData[index + 1] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swap);
}
```

And finally, you can display the non-sorted and sorted lists of data. Note I added a second question to the user if they choose "Sorted" where they can decide if it should be sorted by File1 or File2:

```
private static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("1 or 2 ?");
    int operation = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    var fileData = GetFileData(@"f:\public\temp\temp1.txt", @"f:\public\temp\temp2.txt");

    if (operation == 1)
    {
        //Display unsorted values
        Console.WriteLine("Unsorted:");
        foreach (var data in fileData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data);
        }
    }

    if (operation == 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sort on File1 or File2 (1 or 2)?");
        operation = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        //sort numbers and display
        SortArray(fileData, operation == 1);
        Console.WriteLine("Sorted: ");
        foreach (var data in fileData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data);
        }
    }

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

If you wanted to use an int to decide which field to sort on, you could do something like the following:

```
public static void SortArray(FileData[] fileData, int sortFileNumber = 1)
{
    bool swap;

    do
    {
        swap = false;
        for (int index = 0; index < (fileData.Length - 1); index++)
        {
            bool comparison;

            // Set our comparison to the field sortFileNumber
            if (sortFileNumber == 1)
            {
                comparison = fileData[index].File1Value > fileData[index + 1].File1Value;
            }
            else if (sortFileNumber == 2)
            {
                comparison = fileData[index].File2Value > fileData[index + 1].File2Value;
            }
            else // File3Value becomes default for anything else
            {
                comparison = fileData[index].File3Value > fileData[index + 1].File3Value;
            }

            if (comparison)
            {
                var temp = fileData[index];
                fileData[index] = fileData[index + 1];
                fileData[index + 1] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swap);
}
```

Comment: Thank you So much. Much appreciated

Comment: Just another question if you could help. If i wanted to add more files what do I need to edit in the sorting  part. I know where to add everything else to make the file work in line. Just not sure about that part. For example if I wanted to add another file called file3 and would I be able to choose between which file I would like to sort from. Thanks again

Comment: There are many ways to do it, I added a Boolean argument to the Sort method that, if false, will make it sort on File2. If you add more files, you could change the Boolean to an int, and then add some logic to determine which field should be the sort target.

Comment: No problem. I updated the sample to ask the user which field they want to sort on, so you can try it out. Marking this as the answer is appreciated if it works for you.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to change the code from bool to int but keep coming up with errors stating that it cannot convert from bool to int. It means im not writing the correct stuff down. I know that I need to add If statements to get the logic side working but whatever I type isnt working. Any tips on what to change to get this working. Thanks

Comment: You must not be changing all the logic to use an int where we were using a bool for the condition statement. I can update with a sample shortly

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. Much appreciated

Comment: Rufus, Could you please help me one more time? I added in a third operation for a binary search. How do I link the files to the binary search  So it uses the sorted array when searching for a number/word rather than pre defined numbers. Please could you help

Comment: If you are adding another operation which requires sorted data, and you want to let the user decide which field to sort on, then you should take the sorting query code out from `if (operation == 2)` and put it in a separate method, so that now you can call it from `operation ==2` AND from `operation ==3`. Then, in `operation == 3` you would also do the binary search stuff now that you have sorted data.

Comment: Take the code that asks the user which field they want to sort on and put it in a method so that you can call that from more than one place

Comment: This is a new question, so you should post what you want to do, along with what you've tried (just the relevant parts to the question), as a new question.

Comment: Ok, not sure why you can't post a new question, but good luck!

Comment: Ok, So I took operation ==2 out of the main and into a method and called it properly back into the main. Could you explain what to do to apply to this to the binary search? The one I currently have is for a int but not always going to be an int

Comment: Not without seeing your code. When you can ask a new question, I will be happy to help. Unfortunatly there [must be some reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) that you can't ask a new question, because the rules are not very strict. Asking folks to go back and edit exiting answers so that they answer a different question is an example of what NOT to do.

Comment: I have realised what I have done wrong. 1 or 2 of my questions were rather vague. Is there any way I can show you what I need help with?

Comment: No, not outside of this site. I would recommend asking your instructor for help. That's what they're there for!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43727243/fixing-my-binary-search-c-sharp New question